# Pandas to get multiple column values when a variable matches another column value that is repeated

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
A   |  B
1     123
2     321
1     456
2     999
1     888
3     333
2     422
```

I have a variable x that contains (1,2,3) so when i match it to column A with variable x being 1 it should give me:

```
123 
456
888
```

the code i am using right now is:

```
df.loc(df[A] == x, 'B').iloc[0]
```

This gives me only 123.

P.S : I would like to add these values in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['A'] == x, 'B']
```

or

```
df[df['A'] == x]['B']
```

Comment: Can i put this into a list??

Comment: `df.loc[df'A'] == x,  'B'].tolist()`  is recommended over the second method which uses index chaining and is generally bad practice in pandas.

Comment: @ScottBoston I figured it out.. the one you mentioned didnt work for me the error being `series is mutable, thus not hashable`. This worked for me
`df[df['A'] == x]` and then `d = df['B'].tolist()`

Comment: Eep typo!  `df.loc[df['A'] == x, 'B'].tolist()`